# How to get position called a specific function in source code?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, callstack

I'm checking Memory Leak issue at our Linux C++ Application.
So, I overrode `new` operator to get some information, and one of the information is the position called this overridden `new` operator in source code.

I used call-stack, but it is not enough and too slow.
( `new` operators are called many times in our application. )

I tried to get the position by using default argument as below.

```
Overriding "new" : void* operator new(size_t size){ }
Overriding "new" with default argument : void* operator new(size_t size, char *str = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__){ }
```

However, `void* operator new(size_t size, char *str = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__){ }` doesn't override `new` operator.

How should I get the position called overridden `new` operator in source code without call-stack?

Comment: It's not easy. What's easy is to forget trying to find the memory leaks yourself, and simply use valgrind, and let it do all the hard work of locating the exact source of every memory leak.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location

Comment: You probably don't want to manually instrument your code.  There are a several good memory leak detection tools on Linux at your disposal: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/how-to-find-memory-leaks/

Comment: If I read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) correctly. User defined arguments are only allowed for placement new operator. So, you are out of luck here.

Comment: `operator new` is an allocation function. It is not the same "new" as in a new-expression. Your second override is a "placement new" and would be used like `new ("here") T`, where `"here"` gets passed to the function - the default argument is useless (literally, as it will never be used). Also, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`  will not have a meaningful value in the declaration of `operator new`.

Comment: Also instrumenting your code as a tendency to change the behavior of the code.
Other options : split your code in smaller libraries and make unit tests for those libs and see if they leak (having unit tests is a good idea anyway). Narrow down memory leak to specific use case (which can help narrow down the code you need to check). And start refactoring all naked new/delete calls to std::make_unique (or std::make_shared). You can still keep naked pointers on calls (non-owning uses).